# Copying single cell value when multiples exist in one column in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to copy ID numbers from one spreadsheet with the raw data to the spreadsheet with the countifs formulas that works everything out for me. But each ID number has multiple entries so it is repeated many times in the ID column of the raw data sheet. I would like to copy one ID number for all of the ID numbers entered in the raw data sheet, is there a way to ask Excel to ignore these multiple entries and copy only one across? I've attached an example screenshot but I have thousands of entries so it would not be possible to do this manually. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? If you are using 365 or 2021 the `UNIQUE` function will do this. If an older version see this post: https://superuser.com/questions/49614/how-do-i-get-the-distinct-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this function but it has now worked! If you can reply as an answer I can give you credit?

Comment: Micaela Mossop done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Excel are you using? If you are using 365 or 2021 the `UNIQUE` function will do this. If an older version see this post: https://superuser.com/questions/49614/how-do-i-get-the-distinct-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel